# Graphical diff for darcs

Tags: diff, darcs, visual-diff

I don't feel very comfortable seeing the darcs changes in plain text format, so I've been looking for a tool to display a nice side-by-side comparison of the changes.

For the `whatsnew` I can just use `meld`, but when I need see the changes already recorded it does not work as easily. I've read that `diffuse` allows to compare different revisions, but I cannot get it to work.

I've tried

```
diffuse -r HEAD^1 -r HEAD^2 myfile.py
```

but it fails (I think that revision naming is specific to git), so does somebody know how to see the latest changes in darcs?

Suggestions for other tool that does the work (and does not require to set up a web server preferably) are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fact you should write something like:

```
darcs diff --diff-command="diffuse %1 %2" myfile.txt
```

It works with ECMerge (the tool I work on), it should work seamlessly with diffuse. Darcs will call diffuse with temporary files as necessary (to compare the files from the repository). By the way, ECMerge can dig in Darcs configurations with its browser UI.

EDITED:

to diff tags or patches in the repository, use `--from-tag=` or `--from-patch=`  and `--to-tag=` or `--to-patch=` notation. You should be able to do what you want, however note that `from-patch` means "from before patch" and `--to-patch` means "up to after patch". it was not really obvious for me...
(to know the last of changes use `darcs changes`)

Comment: that works just for **unrecorded** changes (like `whatsnew`), and I was already able to do that with `meld` :-/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to integrate with darcs, but [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is a wonderful graphical diff/merge application available both for linux, macos and windows.